# Recuperar registro do banco de dados e exibir na tela do usuario com Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Eu sou iniciante e estou com dificuldades para conseguir retornar os dados do banco de dados e exibir na tela.
Tenho o  seguinte cenário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um campo input para colocar os números de um CPF que já tem registrado no banco de dados(MEU OBJETIVO É BUSCAR ESSA INFORMAÇÃO E EXIBIR APENAS ELA NA TELA).

Como mostra na imagem, todos os registros do banco de dados estão retornando na tela e eu preciso saber como corrigir isso.

Ao clicar no botão Consultar, ele deve me retornar o registro com base no cpf informado.

Estou usando o Laravel 8, Banco de dados MySql.

Segue meu código para comparação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Route::get('/teste', [MatriculaController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('/create', [MatriculaController::class, 'create']);

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div style="display: block; margin-bottom: 0;">

        <div class="btn-consulta">
            <form method="GET" action="/teste" >
                @csrf

                <table style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            CPF: <input type="text" name="cpf_consulta" size="10" placeholder="só numeros"/>
                                
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Consultar</button>
                                
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </form>
        </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div style="display: flex">
                
                <table class="table table-primary table-hover">                   
                    
                    <thead class="thead-primary">

                        <th> ID </th>                
                        <th> Nome </th>
                        <th> Data de Nascimento</th>
                        <th> RG </th>
                        <th> CPF </th>
                        <th> Sexo </th>                        

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach ($dados as $dado)

                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ $dado->id }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $dado->nome_completo }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $dado->data_nascimento }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $dado->rg }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $dado->cpf }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $dado->sexo }} </td>                               
                            </tr>
                            
                        @endforeach
                        
                    </tbody>                       

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$alunos = DB::table('inscricaos')
                      ->join('areas', 'inscricaos.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
                      ->join('planos', 'inscricaos.plano_id', '=', 'planos.id')
                      ->join('carreiras', 'inscricaos.carreira_id', '=', 'carreiras.id')
                      ->select('inscricaos.id', 'inscricaos.nome_completo', 'inscricaos.cpf', 
                               'areas.nome as area', 'planos.tipo', 'planos.desc', 'carreiras.nome as carreira')
                      //->where('inscricaos.id', '=', $id)                      
                      ->get();

$dados = DB::table('inscricaos')
          ->select('inscricaos.id', 'inscricaos.nome_completo',      
                   'inscricaos.data_nascimento',                   
                   'inscricaos.rg','inscricaos.cpf',inscricaos.sexo')                                                           
          ->get();


        $array = array(
            'alunos' => $alunos,
            'dados' => $dados,
        );
      
        return view('/teste', $array);
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas e descobri que tem como fazer uma requisição AJAX para obter esses dados, mas como sou iniciante eu estou tendo muita dificuldade para resolver essa questão.

OBS: No print da tela do Controller, tem uma parta com a variável $alunos e um innerJoin, no caso essa parte esta OK, é da variável $dados para baixo que é o problema.

Comment: @Danizavtz obrigado pela dica, editei a postagem inserindo os códigos em texto.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso.

A mais fácil(porém não performática); É usando datatables direto no DOM.

REF: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.table').DataTable(); 
});
```